# AppleScript does not work, JSON Helper installed

Tags: api, applescript

I have JSON Helper installed but I can't seem to get this script to work.

```
set myjson to (do shell script "curl http://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x3E306757A30fa6cB302109D11646428e20a91369?apiKey=freekey")

tell application "JSON Helper" to set mydata to (read JSON from myjson)

set value1 to balance of (item 1 of tokens of mydata)

set myjson to (do shell script "curl https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/streamr-datacoin/")

tell application "JSON Helper" to set mydata to (read JSON from myjson)

set value2 to price_usd of item 1 of mydata

set total to value1 * value2

return total
```

My problems lies in the fact that value two is returned with an error saying: `Can’t make "0.0246031406" into type number.`

Comment: it seems a bit off that it does not work with me. It seems that value1 is fine and results to a: 2.83262816586597E+23 (which is an actual number. It seems like the result of value2 is not a number as it results to "0.0248586567" (I guess this is a string isn't it?) and that is why the calculation does not work, number * string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall from back when I used to use *`JSON Helper`*, it has a specific command for making a call to a remote API endpoint.  Currently, you're doing this with `cURL` by creating a shell process.  There's nothing massively wrong with this, and were I in a terminal, that's certainly how I'd do it.

But, aside from the additional overhead from using `do shell script`, doing it this way creates an additional necessary step: `call to <API> -> receive <response> as text -> convert <response> to record`.

If you use `fetch JSON from` instead, you eliminate the need to call out to the shell, and you eliminate a step in the workflow: `call to <API> -> receive <response> as record`.

```
property url1 : "http://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x3E306757A30fa6cB302109D11646428e20a91369?apiKey=freekey"
property url2 : "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/streamr-datacoin/"


-- First API call
tell application "JSON Helper" to fetch JSON from url1
set value1 to the contents of the result's tokens's 1st item's balance 

-- Second API call
tell application "JSON Helper" to fetch JSON from url2
set value2 to contents of the result's 1st item's price_usd

set amount to (value1 as number) * (value2 as number)
return the amount
```

---

Alternatively, you can do away with the *`JSON Helper`* as well, and use the AppleScript-Objecive-C bridge to call the API and parse the JSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property url1 : "http://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x3E306757A30fa6cB302109D11646428e20a91369?apiKey=freekey"
property url2 : "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/streamr-datacoin/"

to numberFromString:(nmbrString as text)
        local nmbrString

        tell alloc() of NSNumberFormatter ¬
                of the current application
                init()
                setNumberStyle_(1) -- decmial 
                numberFromString_(nmbrString)
                return result's floatValue()
        end tell
end numberFromString:

to unwrap(nsObject)
        local nsObject

        tell current application to tell its NSArray to ¬
                tell the arrayWithObject_(nsObject) to ¬
                        get the 1st item in (it as list)
end unwrap

on response from api for keypath as list : ["@self"]
        local api, keypath

        script
                property _ : a reference to missing value
                property a : URLWithString_(api) of my NSURL
                property b : dataWithContentsOfURL_(a) of my NSData
                property c : (my NSJSONSerialization)'s ¬
                            JSONObjectWithData:b ¬
                            options:0 |error|:_

                property list : arrayWithArray_(keypath) of my NSArray
                property key : componentsJoinedByString_(".") of my list
                property value : the valueForKeyPath_(key) of c
        end script
end response

set value1 to value of the (response from url1 for ["tokens", "balance", "@firstObject"])
set value2 to value of the (response from url2 for "price_usd.@firstObject")

return {value1 as real, value2 as real}
```

Too multiply those two values, delete the `return` statement, then:

```
set amount to (value 1 as real) * (value2 as real)
```

To round that `amount` to 2 decimal places:

```
set amount_2dp to (round (amount * 100)) / 100
```

Comment: I will remove all the other comments after. Thank you. after some nil errors it indeed returns as {2.83262816586597E+23, 0.0234295304}. I can use a multiplication on these numbers then yes? Again I'm no programmer, so I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how I can accomplish this. After multiplying both returns I'm hoping to have something formatted like this 6515,04. May I ask you if you would be so kind to write that too? I'm not sure where to start with the results I'm getting now.

Comment: Hey thanks for selecting the answer.  I have been a bit busy today and haven't had time to answer your latest queries, so I hope you don't mind that I have to postpone it until tomorrow.  Quickly, though, to multiply those two values together, replace `return {value1 as real, value2 as real}` with `return (value1 as real) * (value2 as real)`

Comment: Since your AppleScript engine seems broken , in that it cannot coerce appropriate strings to numbers, you'll maybe want to keep hold of the `numberFromString:` handler to use in other scripts.  String-to-number coercion is a common need in many scripts.  You'd need to include the first two `use` lines of the script in any other script that uses the `numberFromString:` handler.